# Style not setting from custom attribute defined in theme.xml

Tags: android, styling, android-custom-attributes

I'm attempting to utilize theming to create a night mode theme. However, it seems that the style isn't being set correctly.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?commentHeader">
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="AppTheme">
        <attr name="commentHeader" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**theme.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="commentHeader">@style/CommentHeaderLight</item>
</style>
```

**theme.xml:CommentHeaderLight**

```
<style name="CommentHeaderLight">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/comment_header_background</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
</style>
```

The final view displays with a stock background and no padding. Am I tackling this issue correctly, or is there another way to do this?